# Htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forwarding

Does anyone have a simple way of rdirected in .htaccess all pages that were once .asp to now be .php. For example index.asp is now index.php etc. Server is apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.asp$ $1.php
```